# Set overlay height equal to parent div, not equal toscreen height

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to highlight select div when mouse click event.
To implement this, I used this code snippet

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="subcontent-1">
     ...
    </div>
    <div class="highlight">
    ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

To overlay, I used following css

```
.overlay{
    display:none;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.44);
    z-index: 3;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
}
```

But this overlay only fill the screen height not the full page height (the parent div overflows screen height)
[This is how it looks like now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xh5ym.png)
I want stretch this overlay to the bottom of page, not height of screen.

Comment: If you want your `.overlay` to fit exactly the size of the parent, use `position: relative` on said parent, in addition to `position: absolute` on the `.overlay`.

Comment: But when I use ```position:relative```, it doesn't showing the overlay

Comment: This is what I meant https://codepen.io/SimplyCius/pen/XWdyLqK

Comment: Oh, Ok, Thanks, it also works

Comment: Glad I could help you. You might accept the answer below from @vodkaJedi. If however not so detailed, he meant exactly the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try add `position: relative;` to your parent div.

Answer (score 1):

I found a answer
I think the in the `position:absolute` property, `bottom:0` is bottom of screen.
When I used `position:fixed` it solved the problem.
In this case the `bottom:0` works as bottom of parent div(the page)
The overlay is filled entire page.

Comment: if you having a bigger height page that need to scroll.. i dont think `fixed` position will works in your case

Comment: The page is currently overflows the screen height, as you can see in the image link.
I use ```position:fixed``` and it solves problem.